# Error starting the program with google drive API

Tags: c#

I'm trying to start an application by logging into google drive with client_id.json, but when I start the program, it says: "The file 'C: \ Windows \ system32 \ client_id.json' could not be located.", this file is in the program folder. I do not know why it tries to fetch on system32.

```
public Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.UserCredential Autenticar()
{
    string caminhoarquivo = @"c:\ProComercio\";

    //Se o diretório não existir, ele irá criar esse novo diretório
    if (!Directory.Exists(caminhoarquivo))
    {
        //Criamos um com o nome folder
        Directory.CreateDirectory(caminhoarquivo);
    }
    string fileName = "client_id.json";
    string sourcePath = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    string targetPath = @"c:\ProComercio\";
    string sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcePath, fileName);
    string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);
    System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true);
    using (var ctx = new Entities())
    {
        //Busca o email na tabela parametros
        var resultado = ctx.Clientes.SqlQuery("Select * from tblParametros").FirstOrDefault();

        Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.UserCredential credenciais;

        using (var stream = new System.IO.FileStream(caminhoarquivo + "client_id.json", System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read))
        {
            var diretorioAtual = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
            var diretorioCredenciais = System.IO.Path.Combine(diretorioAtual, "credential");

            credenciais = Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    new[] { Google.Apis.Drive.v3.DriveService.Scope.Drive },
                    resultado.mailuser,
                    System.Threading.CancellationToken.None,
                    new Google.Apis.Util.Store.FileDataStore(diretorioCredenciais, true)).Result;
        }
        return credenciais;
    }
}
```

Comment: When you look at the value of `sourcePath` in the debugger, what do you see?

Comment: It returns this here :  sourcePath "C:\\Downloads\\TrabalhoRGS\\RGS.Procomercio.Windowsforms\\bin\\Debug" string

Comment: Well, something, somewhere in your code is looking for "client_id.json" in System32. All you can do is find out where that happens. It's going to happen right around where that exception gets thrown. Maybe the current directory changes. This is something you can track down in the debugger. Put in a conditional breakpoint with a condition `sourcePath.Contains("system32")`  as the condition.

Comment: I'm debugging here, but it does not show up anywhere where it tries to find System32, I think it's because I'm trying to start the program through Windows Service, so whenever I start the computer it gives the error, when I start normally without restarting it finds the file. He gives this error here when restarting the computer: The file could not be found 'C:\Windows\system32\client_id.json'.   em System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)

Comment: OK, so on system startup, it starts up with system32 as the current directory. That makes sense to me. I think you should put the correct path for that JSON file in config, rather than relying on the current directory.